# Compare the previous N rows to the current row in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to populate a new column in my pandas dataframe by considering the values of the previous n rows. If the current value is not equal to any of the past n values in that column, it should populate "N", else "Y".

Please let me know what would be a good way to achieve this.

Here's my input data :

```py
testdata = {'col1' :['car','car','car','bus','bus','bus','car']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(testdata)
```

Input DF:

```
  col1
0  car
1  car
2  car
3  bus
4  bus
5  car  
6  car
```

Output DF (with n=2):

```
  col1   Result
0  car         
1  car         
2  car      Y  
3  bus      N  
4  bus      Y  
5  bus      Y  
6  car      N
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my way

```
n=2
l=[False]*n+[df.iloc[x,0] in df.iloc[x-n:x,0].tolist() for x in np.arange(n,len(df))]
df['New']=l
df
  col1    New
0  car  False
1  car  False
2  car   True
3  bus  False
4  bus   True
5  bus   True
6  car  False
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Would it be possible to put blank instead of False the initial 2 rows?

Comment: @tipsydeepz change [False]*n to [‘’]*n

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: May i ask if there is any easier way to insert value in the new column only when the value changes from True to False or False to True.(blank repeated results)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a [**`Rolling.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) call.

```
n = 2
res = (df['col1'].astype('category')
                 .cat.codes
                 .rolling(n+1)
                 .apply(lambda x: x[-1] in x[:-1], raw=True))

df['Result'] = np.where(res == 1, 'Y', 'N')
df

  col1 Result
0  car      N
1  car      N
2  car      Y
3  bus      N
4  bus      Y
5  bus      Y
6  car      N
```

Rolling only works with numeric data, so the initial step is to factorise it. This can be done in many ways, I've used `astype('category')` and then extracted the codes.

---

Another option is using `pd.Categorical` for the conversion,

```
res = (df.assign(col1=pd.Categorical(df['col1']).codes)['col1']
         .rolling(n+1)
         .apply(lambda x: x[-1] in x[:-1], raw=True))

df['Result'] = res.map({1: 'Y', 0: 'N'})
df

  col1 Result
0  car    NaN
1  car    NaN
2  car      Y
3  bus      N
4  bus      Y
5  bus      Y
6  car      N
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. But i am getting an error data type "category" not understood. Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: @tipsydeepz What is your version? I've edited with an additional option.

Comment: Currently on 3.4.3. I have latest version on another machine. Will be able to try on it later.

Comment: @tipsydeepz I meant your pandas version... either way, please check the edit. Thanks.

Comment: I am on an online platform and it's using older pandas version. I will check this on the latest version and update you after sometime. Thanks a lot for your time.