# Pandas check if any of previous n rows met criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say i have this data set.

```
|    | color  | down | top |
| -- | ------ | ---- | --- |
| 0  |        | 1    | 5   |
| 1  |        | 2    | 5   |
| 2  | blue   | 7    | 11  |
| 3  |        | 5    | 8   |
| 4  |        | 9    | 10  |
| 5  |        | 9    | 10  |
| 6  | orange | 5    | 9   |
| 7  |        | 4    | 7   |
| 8  |        | 5    | 10  |
| 9  |        | 5    | 6   |
| 10 |        | 3    | 7   |
```

I want to flag rows where any of the 3 previous rows are either blue or orange AND where current top is between down and top of that row.

The outcome of this operation would be a dataset:

```
|    | color  | down | top | blue_condition | orange_condition |
| -- | ------ | ---- | --- | -------------- | ---------------- |
| 0  |        | 1    | 5   |                |                  |
| 1  |        | 2    | 5   |                |                  |
| 2  | blue   | 7    | 11  |                |                  |
| 3  |        | 5    | 8   | 1              |                  |
| 4  |        | 9    | 10  | 1              |                  |
| 5  |        | 9    | 10  | 1              |                  |
| 6  | orange | 5    | 9   |                |                  |
| 7  |        | 4    | 7   |                | 1                |
| 8  |        | 5    | 10  |                |                  |
| 9  |        | 5    | 6   |                | 1                |
| 10 |        | 3    | 7   |                |                  |
```

I have been fiddling around with combinations between `.tail()`, `.filter()` and `.assign()`. But I am a bit stuck to be honest.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"color": [None, None, 'blue', None, None, None, 'orange', None, None, None, None],
                   'down': [1, 2, 7, 5, 9, 9, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3],
                   'top': [5, 5, 11, 8, 10, 10, 9, 7, 10, 6, 7]})

# get latest 3 records
df['blue_condition'] = df.tail(3)

# assign using lambda
df['blue_condition'].assign(blue_condition=lambda x: (x.tail(3).query(top < top.tail(3))))
```

I have looked into other questions but they don't take the current row as a reference, from what I can tell.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74734980/pandas-return-true-if-condition-true-in-any-of-previous-n-rows](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573008/compare-the-previous-n-rows-to-the-current-row-in-a-pandas-column](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)+[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) the data and use this to compare to the top value:

```
N = 3
df2 = (df.pivot(columns='color', values=['top', 'down'])
         .drop(columns=np.nan, level=1)
         .ffill(limit=N-1).shift()
      )

out = df.join((df2['down'].le(df['top'], axis=0)
             & df2['top'].ge(df['top'], axis=0)).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
     color  down  top  blue  orange
0     None     1    5     0       0
1     None     2    5     0       0
2     blue     7   11     0       0
3     None     5    8     1       0
4     None     9   10     1       0
5     None     9   10     1       0
6   orange     5    9     0       0
7     None     4    7     0       1
8     None     5   10     0       0
9     None     5    6     0       1
10    None     3    7     0       0
```

Comment: wow that is a lot to digest haha. Seems like a clever approach. How does this work when i would have an additional bool column `sun_is_shining` which needs to be true? Then I need to make a third df, shift it and then join with another & ?

Comment: Just found some time to try it out. It works! Thnx. Need some time understand though

Comment: Let me know if you have any question!

Comment: Hmm I think I understand a bit. I do have some questions. But out of scope of this topic. Added a new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75671167/pandas-update-previous-records-because-future-peaking-is-not-possible

Comment: Well one question related to this... do you see alternatives to the usage of pivots? Maybe a loop or something. I was thinking if there will be a lot more colors the dataframe gets really big.  Thnx anyway! Made my day

Comment: @Florian I answered to the other question, let me know if this works for you (if this is that simple, maybe I can just add a note here instead of a new question). Regarding the `pivot`, it depends also on `N`. If you have a small `N` a loop over the different values might be sufficient, if both `N` and the number of colors are large, well we would need to see a real example ;)