# Python Pandas: How to flag n next rows satisfying some conditions? (Identify period after shortage)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, rolling-computation

I'm currently facing a retail problem which can be described as follows:

- Few days after a product becomes available again (after a shortage period), orders are abnormally high.
- In order to not account for these orders, I wanted to flag the days when these peaks occur.

My dataframe is the following:

| Date | Item | stock (bool) | work_day (bool) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/08/23 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 11/08/23 | A | 0 | 0 |
| 12/08/23 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 13/08/23 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 14/08/23 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 15/08/23 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 16/08/23 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 10/08/23 | B | 1 | 1 |
| 11/08/23 | B | 1 | 0 |

First, I compute the cumulative count of days in shortage (out of stock) given this criteria:

- rolling count of 2 days
- only consider `work_day == 1` for rolling count
- only consider previous days, not current day

That, I can do:

```
rolling_func = lambda x: x.shift().rolling(2, min_periods=2).sum()
df['shortage_count'] = (df.assign(stock = df.stock.where(df.work_day == 1)).groupby('ITEM').stock.transform(rolling_func))
```

| Date | Item | stock (bool) | work_day (bool) | shortage_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/08/23 | A | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 11/08/23 | A | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12/08/23 | A | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 13/08/23 | A | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 14/08/23 | A | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 15/08/23 | A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 16/08/23 | A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10/08/23 | B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 11/08/23 | B | 1 | 0 | 0 |

**Now, my problem:**

*How do I flag `x` rows after a shortage period of minimum 'y' days? Such that flagged days verify `work_day == 1`?*

For example, if `x = 3` and `y = 2`, I would like to flag - for product A - days 14/08/23, 15/08/23, 16/08/23.

**In wanted to use the following logic to answer that question, but cannot figure out how to do this in pandas**:

- Create column "flag"
- For each row, whose `shortage_count >= 2`
- Assign `flag = 1` to the 3 next rows which verify `work_day == 1`. (it means I might have to look at 5 rows for example to reach the next 3 meeting the criteria)

Moreover, I wanted the code to be applicable to the entire dataframe - per product. That is, using *groupby* and *transform*.

Is there a way to achieve my goal like this our should I take another approach?
Thanks in advance!

Note: I thought about the approach depicted in [Pandas check if any of previous n rows met criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75653925/pandas-check-if-any-of-previous-n-rows-met-criteria) but I don't think it fits my case.